# C# Linq to Entity Framework multiple unrelated queries

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I need data from multiple database tables.

**Table 1** - has list of columns which needs to be displayed on front end html, angular kendo grid - which is configurable from separate Admin configuration.

**Table 2** (joining of some other tables)- has the data which needs to be displayed on the angular front end.

My linq here which I am using currently is as below.

**Query 1**: to get list of columns to be displayed on Grid

```
var columns = from cols in _context.columns
              select cols.colNames;
```

**Query 2**: Get the actual data for list

```
var data = from cust in _context.customer
           join details in _context.custDetails on cust.id equals details.custid
           join o in _context.orders on cust.id equals o.custid
           where cust.id == XXXX
           select new Customer
           {
            Id = cust.Id,
            Name = cust.Name,
            Address = details.Address,
            City = details.City,
            State = details.State,
            OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
            Amount = o.Amount
           //15 other properties similarly
          };
```

returns IQueryable type to Kendo DataSourceRequest

Currently, From my ui I have been make two api calls one for columns and one for getting the actual data, and show/hide the columns which are configured in the columns table.

But the problem is if anyone looks at the api calls on the network or on browser tools they could see the data being returned for the columns that are to be hidden which is a security problem.

I am looking for a single query for my api which returns the data using second query which should be smart enough to send the data only for configured columns (there could be 30 different columns) and set the other properties to null or doesn't select them at all. there are some properties which needs to be returned always as they are being used for some other purpose.

I searched many resources on how could I generate dynamic linq select using the configured columns.

Please some one help me in resolving this problem

Comment: your Angular UI is calling Web API which in turns in turns calls SQL, correct? and you return data to UI in some format (might be JSon Format)? so where do you want encryption? between Client and Web API or between Web API or SQL?

Comment: @Viru I think he wants to filter the data so that no sensitive data gets transmitted from the server, not just encrypting it which will let any user see the sensitive data in the browser debug tools.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Ya got it thanks

Comment: @Shashi so which columns are configured to show/hide...is that information available in database? or is it in some config file?

Comment: @Viru Yes the data is returned to ui in JSON format, Configuration is in the database, I don't want the data to be encrypted as its the same data I wanted to show when I configure it to be shown

Comment: Based on your queries, do you want something like setting `Address = columns.Contains('Address') ? details.Address : null;` in your `select new Customer`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this. Assuming you columns tables a Boolean column Display and when it is true Column will be displayed and when it is false it wont be displayed.

```
 var columns = (from cols in _context.columns
                  select cols).ToList(); // note I am getting everything not just column names here...


   var data = from cust in _context.customer
           join details in _context.custDetails on cust.id equals details.custid
           join o in _context.orders on cust.id equals o.custid
           where cust.id == XXXX
           select new Customer
           {
            Id = cust.Id,
            Name = cust.Name,
            Address = details.Address,
            City = details.City,
            State = details.State,
            OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
            Amount = o.Amount
           //15 other properties similarly
          }.ToList();

var fileterdData = from d in data
                   select new Customer
                  {
                     Id = DisplayColumn("ID",columns)? cust.Id:null,
                     Name =  DisplayColumn("Name",columns)? cust.Name:null,
                     Address =  DisplayColumn("Address",columns)? details.Address:null,
                      // do similarly for all other columns
                  }.AsQueryable(); // returns IQueryable<Customer>

private bool DisplayColumnn(string columnName,List<Columns> cols)
{
return cols.Where(x=>x.ColumnName==columnName).First().Display();
}
```

So now you will have this code as part of one web API call which is going to do two SQL calls one to get columns and other to get data then you will use Linq To Entity filter columns which you dont want ( or want them to null). return this filtered data back to UI.

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work as its trying to access a collection from outside I get an error saying linq to entity cannot find.

Comment: I see I think you have to get data completely and materialize the query and then use the other query to fileter the columns...will post updated code in a min

Comment: Error:Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are

Comment: have you materialized the query? it is important you do ToList for both the Linq query....can you post update code?

Comment: I have done tolist for first query, I can't do to list for second query as i want my method to return iqueryable type for kendo mapper to allow server side sorting and filtering

Comment: I just checked it works if I don't do to list but the second query takes lot of time, may be its trying to execute first query foe each and every property and for all rows

Comment: you are saying it works when you do ToList only to first one and use it in second query....I wonder how it is working...how LinqProviders is able to translate your first query which is Linq to Entiy in SQL queries.....I think you are doing something differently which your question does not tell us......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105088/discussion-between-shashi-and-viru).

Comment: @Shashi Sorry I can't do chat..Workplace firewall policy does not allow that